# Redirect after registration in BuddyPress

Tags: buddypress

In Buddypress, after Registration first step, users are redirected to Change Avatar step. Im trying to find a way to redirect to an alternate page, for example: http://www.mysite.com/yeah Im using the following code, but Im continuously redirected to Change Avatar page.

```
function custom_filter_bp_signup() {

    global $current_site;

    return 'http://' . $current_site->domain . $current_site->path . 'yeah';

} 

add_filter('wp_signup_location', 'custom_filter_bp_signup');
```

Any help is welcome,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Which php file are you editing to fix this problem?

Comment: function.php inside your theme, or inside your custom plugin methods.

Comment: Unless there's a separate forum for wordpress plugins, i think this is exactly the right forum for questions about wordpress plugins. Or at least better than a thread for generic php questions. It's not a "how do i do php" question. It's a "how do i do wordpress" question. As a wordpress admin, looking for precisely this question, this is where i'd look-- not in a generic php forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah I ge it:

```
function bp_redirect($user) {

    $redirect_url = 'http://www.mysite.com/yeah';

    bp_core_redirect($redirect_url);

}

add_action('bp_core_signup_user', 'bp_redirect', 100, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function your_function($signup) {
   // $signup is the user id of the person who has just been added  
}
add_filter( 'bp_core_activate_account', 'your_function' );
```